# How to bind the same collection of values into all ComboBoxes in a DataGridComboBox?

Tags: wpf, binding, wpfdatagrid

I have a Collection of Values in an Array of Strings, or in a List or whatever, and what i want is to set this Collection of values as the Collection of items into all the ComboBoxes in a column as DataGridComboBoxColumn in WPF.

I think i don't have other way to access this Collection of Values and bind it equally to all the ComboBoxes (in XAML) beside the DataContext. But can i access the DataContext of a DataGrid from a DatGridComboBoxColumn (in XAML)? Can i do it? How?

How i specify (in XAML) in DatagridComboBoxColumn to put this Collection of Items equally in all ComboBoxes? How i can achieve this?

Here is my XAML:

```
(...)xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp"(...)

<Grid Name="grid1">
    <DataGrid Name="dataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="True">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Options" Width="100"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

And here is my Code Behind:

```
public class TestClass
{
    private static string[] stringArray = { "Option One", "Option Two", "Option Three" };

    public static string[] StringArray
    {
        get
        {
            return stringArray;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not very clear what you want, could you elaborate?

Comment: I've edited the explanation of my problem, i hope that now you can understand what i want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But can i access the DataContext of a DataGrid from a DatGridComboBox Column (in XAML)? Can i do it? How?

There's no straightforward way to access the `DataContext` of the `DataGrid` from the column definition, because it isn't part of the visual or logical tree, so it doesn't inherit the DataContext. I recently blogged about [a solution to that issue](http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2011/03/21/wpf-how-to-bind-to-data-when-the-datacontext-is-not-inherited/). Basically you need to do something like that:

```
<DataGrid Name="dataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="True">
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <!-- Proxy for the current DataContext -->
        <local:BindingProxy x:Key="proxy" Data="{Binding"} />
    </DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Options" Width="100"
                                ItemsSource="{Binding Source="{StaticResource proxy}", Path=Data}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

`BindingProxy` is a simple class that derives from `Freezable` and exposes a `Data` dependency property.

Comment: Have a look at my XAML, i have adapted to your xample. Something is wrong in my Code, because my Property in the Class give an error.

Comment: It gives an error, it says the Property 'StringArray' was not found in type 'TestClass'.

Comment: @Miguel, that's because the property is static. You don't need a binding in that case, you can just use `{x:Static local:TestClass.StringArray}`

Comment: In this case is. But this is only a test i was doing to understand how it works. But i don't really need another Class to do this, right? Can i access any variable in the main class of the Window and use it? And the variable can be anything with any Data?

Comment: In my real case, i will read the Data, and put in an array of strings. The method you have blogged will work?

Comment: @Miguel, yes it should work. This technique just gives you access to the DataContext in a place where it isn't "naturally" available

Comment: If i set a DataTable to be the ItemsSource of the Datagrid, how i specify to be auto-selected the item correponding to the value in each ComboBoxCell?

Comment: Use the SelectedItemBinding of the DataGridComboBoxColumn: `SelectedItemBinding="{Binding TheColumnToBind}"`

Comment: I already tried with SelectedItemBinding, and SelectedValueBinding and SelectedValuePath and none of the them seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

In a binding where you only specify the `Path` the binding mechanism will implicitly use the `DataContext` as the source. You only need to explicitly specify a source to avoid this (since you do not want the current row as your source).

In one of my test applications i have a class `Employee` which has a few properties including `Occupation`, to use this with a ComboBox-column you need a list of occupations, where and how you define that list is up to you, one way to do is in the resources of the window or DataGrid:

```
    <col:ArrayList x:Key="Occupations">
        <sys:String>Programmer</sys:String>
        <sys:String>GUI Designer</sys:String>
        <sys:String>Coffee Getter</sys:String>
    </col:ArrayList>
```

where `col` is the namespace: `clr-namespace:System.Collections;assembly=mscorlib`

To use this now i can specify the following in the `DataGrid.Columns`:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Occupation}"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Occupations}}"/>
```

This will allow me to assign one of the three "occupations" from my array as the `Occupation` of the employee in question.

Another way to set up your source list is as a static property of some class that way you should be able to use:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn ... ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static namespace:Class.Property}}"/>
```

Comment: I'm quite sure you did it not *exactly* like i suggested, because this stuff works for me.

Comment: Why do you create an anonymous type for the DataContext? I'd suggest you try to just set `DataContext = abc` and bind directly to the DataContext: `ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}, Path=DataContext}"`

Comment: I have done exactly how you said. I have uptated my XAML and Code Behind above so you can see what i am doing wrong.

Comment: Sorry, i forgot about the visual tree of the DataGrid which is disconnected, you cannot get it via relative source binding as you could do with other item controls like a ListView, see the other answer if you really need to do it via DataContext.