# WPF Wait for Binding to be done

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I got the following XAML:

```
<ng:Chart Palette="TheTreesPalette">
    <ng:Chart.Diagrams>
        <Diagram Key="PersonnelHoursAWeek" For="{Binding}" Value="BarSeries3D" />
        <Diagram Key="PersonId" For="{Binding}" Value="BarSeries3D" />
    </ng:Chart.Diagrams>
</ng:Chart>
```

In code:

- Chart is a plain ContentControl.
- Diagrams is a collection (and DependencyObject) and DependencyProperty from Chart
- Diagram is a DependencyObject within Diagrams

My Chart needs to be updated when a Diagram will be added to the Diagrams list. By using DependencyProperty.Register, i've registered the "Diagrams" list, but it won't await the binding (so the For property (of Diagram) is empty when the "event" is passed through).

chart.cs:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty DiagramsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Diagrams", typeof(SkillsNG.Application.Behaviors.DiagramCollection), typeof(Chart), new UIPropertyMetadata(null, FunctionToCall));
private static void FunctionToCall(DependencyObject @this, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
}
```

What can I do to get a filled For property?

By the way, the event "Loaded" still hasn't got the binding.

To explain a little more:
A chart can have multiple bars/lines, the For property will give the dataset to one bar/line (called diagram in my example). Key is the DataMember of it.

The binding is a Binding to a model given to the view. But the Binding can be "Binding Set1" and "Binding Set2" (datasets for the lines that I want to display).

The binding is 100% correct, my chart will show when I just wait one second to bind it all. So I want that eighter Diagram notifies Chart that it has been changed, or Chart that can add an event (Diagram.ForProperty.AddOwner like construction).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your Chart DataContext is set to (that's what the {Binding} on a child element would give you) but the Diagrams collection and it's members are not elements are are not therefore going to be part of the Wpf logical tree, so won't inherit the parent Chart DataContext. I would expect to see Binding errors in the output window to that effect when you run this in debug.

I think you have basically got the same issue as this question: [How to bind the same collection of values into all ComboBoxes in a DataGridComboBox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5446352/how-to-bind-the-same-collection-of-values-into-all-comboboxes-in-a-datagridcombob) which provides a solution for bridging this gap in the Wpf logical tree.

Comment: Binding is correct, I've added some extra text to my initial question.

Comment: Given that the Chart and Diagrams bind to the same DataContext you could do a Dispatcher.BeginInvoke() in the Chart DataContextChanged event - by the time that fires the child controls will have their DataContext. But it seems to me that you actually want the Diagram items to explicitly call Chart when the For property changes and if that's the case perhaps you should just do that in code; i.e. in the Diagram DataContextChanged event find the parent Chart and call a method to notify it to refresh - or execute a custom Command if you want to play it the Wpf way.